# Compile Time Error: Union default constructor is deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, compiler-errors, unions

The following C++ code fails to compile. As far as I have looked into this problem, I understand that the problem is because the default constructor of the union has been deleted by the compiler. The online note says the following:

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial default constructor, the default constructor of the union is deleted by default unless a variant member of the union has a default member initializer.

```
struct A {
   int val;
   A() : val(0) {}
};

union B
{
   A a;
};

B b;
```

Why is the default constructor of struct A considered non-trivial? How do I work around this problem to make this code compile successfully?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572240/why-do-unions-have-a-deleted-default-constructor-if-just-one-of-its-members-does

Comment: I looked at this post before posting this question. However, I am sorry, I could not really understand how to fix the issue.

Comment: @Spinkoo maybe there is a slight difference. This question asks "What's the problem". And that one asks "Why this rule exists"

Comment: Yeah, I am also wondering what is the easiest fix (if any) to the above issue.

Comment: am not sure if this fix is the easiest & the most correct but try declaring inside the union like this A a(); instead of A a

Comment: @Spinkoo: That declares a member function, of course.  But with `{}`…

Comment: Forget the union, struct A contains an A. Is that even legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the default constructor of struct A considered non-trivial?

Because it is user-declared.

Examples of classes that do have a trivial constructor:

```
struct Trivial {
    int val;
};

struct Trivial2 {
    int val;
    Trivial2() = default;
};
```

As a bonus, this is non-trivial:

```
struct NonTrivial {
    int val;
    NonTrivial();
};
NonTrivial::NonTrivial = default;
```

---

If you want `A::val` to be zero-initialised however, you'll want to add a default member initialiser to the union:

```
union B {
   A a = {};
};
```

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm not sure what you refer to. Is it what I appended to the answer?

Comment: That’s it (or just `A a{};`)—but it’s default-initialized, not zero-initialized, even though `val` does become 0.  The important bit is that it makes `B` have a default constructor.