# Union structs that have already been declared

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I'm trying to create a union that contains structs. I plan to have many different structs in the union eventually, so i'd like to declare them before the union, and then just have the structs as a type name.

Here's what i tried:

```
struct Bizz
{
int type;
std::string name;
};

struct Buzz
{
int type;
std::string name;
};

struct Bar
{
std::string name;
union of_type
{
Bizz bizz;
Buzz buzz;
} of_type;
};

struct Baz
{
std::string name;
union of_type
{
Bizz bizz;
Buzz buzz;
};
};

struct Foo
{
int type;
union of_type
{
Bar bar;
Baz baz;
} of_type;
};
```

Of course the names and fields are just examples, but the basic structure is the same.

When i try to assign a value:

```
Foo foo;
foo.type = 1;
foo.of_type.bar.name = "Hello";
```

I get this error:

```
 error: use of deleted function ‘Foo::foo()
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/z/xmf_LY) is enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Why do unions have a deleted default constructor if just one of its members doesn't have one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572240/why-do-unions-have-a-deleted-default-constructor-if-just-one-of-its-members-does)

Comment: So would it be simpler for me to simply define my structs inside the union?

Comment: @IbrahimFadel It has nothing to do with that. You are trying to use a non-trivial type in a union (`std::string`), so you need to define all the special member functions for the union. Just use `std::variant` instead of a union.

Comment: I see, i definitely need to do some more reading on this